# iOS simulator (Xcode 4.5) is much slowerm possible to speed up?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Anyone experienced the differences?

Almost take 7–8 seconds to startup while previously was instantaneous.

Any way to improve?

Comment: I have he same issue - first launch of it is very slow. No idea why at his point. If you leave it running then next app run is fast. I have 4.4.1 on my Mac too might be related...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible, close all other app, this is what you can do